# Split string/list with a char or int

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to make a function in Haskell to split a string at a certain `char` and a list at a certain number.

For doing this the splitAt function is exactly what I need for numbers, but I can't give a char with this function.

E.g.

```
splitAt 5 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

gives

```
([1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10])
```

that is exactly what I needed with the 5 in the left side of the tuple.
But now I want to do this with a `char` and a string. But `splitAt` only takes and `int` for the second argument. I want

```
splitAt 'c' "abcde"
```

resulting in

```
("abc", "de")
```

I looking for something in the direction of

```
splitAt (findIndex 'c' "abcde") "abcde"
```

but the function `findIndex` returns something of the type `Maybe Int` and `splitAt` needs an `Int`. Then I tried the following

```
splitAt (head (findIndices (== 'c') "abcde")) "abcde"
```

This is a possible solution but it returns the following

```
("ab","cde")
```

with the c on the wrong side of the tupple. You can add `succ` to c but what will the result be if the char is a Z.

Is there an easy way to modify to make

```
splitAt (findIndex 'c' "abcde") "abcde"
```

work?

Comment: If you use [`break`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:break)`:: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])` rather than `splitAt`, you don't need `findIndex`.

Comment: @SebastianPaaskeTørholm but you get `'c'` on the right rather than the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `findIndex`, just unwrap the `Maybe` and add one:

```
import Data.List

splitAfter :: (a-> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a],[a])
splitAfter this xs = case findIndex this xs of
    Nothing -> (xs,[])
    Just n -> splitAt (n+1) xs
```

giving, for example

```
*Main> splitAfter (=='c') "abcde"
("abc","de")
```

Maybe is a handy datatype for encoding failure in a way that's easy to recover. There's even a function `maybe :: b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b` to use a default value and a function to handle the two cases separately:

```
splitAfter' :: (a-> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a],[a])
splitAfter' this xs = maybe (xs,[]) 
                  (\n -> splitAt (n+1) xs) 
                  (findIndex this xs)
```

which also works. For example

```
*Main> splitAfter' (==5) [1..10]
([1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the  `fromMaybe` function to take the result from Maybe, for example:

```
splitlist = splitAt (fromMaybe 0 (findIndex 'c' "abcde") "abcde")
```

**fromMaybe :: a -> Maybe a -> a**

> The fromMaybe function takes a default value and Maybe value. If
>   the Maybe is Nothing, it returns the default values; otherwise, it
>   returns the value contained in the Maybe. ([source](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Maybe.html)).

With the default value set to 0, if your findIndex return `Nothing` the result of splitAt will be `("",list)`, for the same case but with default value set to `length list` the finally result it will be `(list,"")`.

Answer (score 1):

Given `c :: Char` and `s :: String`, you can write some as

```
splitAt ((1+) $ fromJust $ findIndex (==c) s) s
```

but

1. you get a exception if `c` is not into `s`
2. you traverse `s` two times

A `Maybe` alternative is

```
maybe Nothing (\x -> splitAt (1+x) s) (findIndex (==c) s)
```

you can set *"else value"* (`Nothing` in my example).

You can write your own function as

```
splitAt' :: Char -> String -> (String, String)
splitAt' _ [] = ("", "")
splitAt' c (x:xs) | c == x = ([c], xs)
                  | True   = (x:cs, ys) where (cs, ys) = splitAt' c xs
```

Then, you get `(s, "")` if not `c` in `s`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different way, that doesn't involve messing around with list indices.

`break` is nearly what you want. Let's reuse it. You want the matching element to be included at the end of the first output list, instead of at the start of the second.

```
import Control.Arrow ((***))

breakAfter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
breakAfter p xs = map fst *** map fst $ break snd (zip xs $ False : map p xs)
```

How this works:

1. Transform our input list into a list of pairs (`zip`). The first element of each pair is taken from the original list. The second element of the pair is a `Bool` stating whether the *previous* element of the list is the one we're looking for. This is why we say `False : map p xs` --- if we just said `map p xs`, we would reproduce exactly the behaviour of `break`. Sticking the extra `False` in at the start is the important bit.
2. Reuse `break`. Our condition is encoded in the second element of each pair.
3. Throw away all those `Bool`s. We don't need them any more.